# Select query with no lock hint on non-modifiable data

Tags: sql-server

I would like to read data from audit table where data is read only and not modified by application. Application only inserts data into the table but not updating existing records.

```
select * from mytable with(nolock) where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I know 'no lock' means getting uncommitted data but I am providing id (1,2,3,4,5) which is commited one. So Is thery any concern or side effect of this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

NOLOCK does mean that you will read 'dirty' data, so you could read back a value that is not committed, this could then be rolled back, meaning the data you have got is not accurate. So, as long as you are happy that you are reading dirty data, you are fine.

It isn't so much about the IDs you are passing to the query, if they weren't there, it just wouldn't return a row.

NOLOCK - you are selecting * in your query, say one column is 'name', the 'name' for ID 1 is 'Test', I open a transaction, update it to be 'LIVE', you then run the above. You would see the 'name' for ID 1 being 'LIVE', I then roll it back so in the data it is actually 'Test', meaning your read was not accurate.

If you did not specify 'NOLOCK' your select would wait until my transaction was finished before returning any data, it it would be the data that has been committed to the database, not the state of the data at the time of read.

Comment: NOLOCK can also cause data to be skipped or duplicated, such as if a page split occurs during allocation order scan.

Comment: @Leonidas199x -  mytable is not updated by application.

Comment: @DeepInJava is the data totally static, is anything or anyone updating it?

Comment: @Leonidas199x- yes data is completely static.

Comment: @DeepInJava then NOLOCK is pretty redundant to be honest, but also won't really do any harm, at least, not to my knowledge.

Comment: Your data is not "completely static" as your application inserts rows

Comment: @DeepInJava you didn't even show your table structure. And if for example it has PK GUID as Dan Guzman said, nolock can cause rows to be skipped or duplicated due to page splits while you are inserting

Comment: @Leonidas199x >>>NOLOCK is pretty redundant to be honest, but also won't really do any harm, at least, not to my knowledge.<<< it's not redundant of course, readers do block writers and writers do block readers. Reader = DeepInJava, writer = the application that inserts. But if that table is blocked entirely or not depends on its structure. If it's a heap without indexes, they block each other always

Comment: @sepupic understood. I was thinking more in terms of, if you legitimately had a read only database, there are no updates being made to records in the table, and you were specifying IDs that were already in the table, if there were guaranteed no updates being done, is there any need for NOLOCK? Interesting about the heap tables however, was not aware of that. Will look into that more.